# Can I override the black background color in SwiftUI dark mode?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to change the black background color globally (app-wide) in SwiftUI dark mode, but I can't find a way to do so, the `.background(View)` modified changes only the background for the view it's applied to, which is not what I'm looking for!

I tried overriding the `UIColor.systemBackground` but it doesn't seem to have any effect actually!

**Edit:** here's a screenshot of what I have right now and what I'm looking for!

[image]

Comment: Just make your own color set, then use it instead of `UIColor.systemBackground`.

Comment: Just the background color of each screen, or for every view?

Comment: @George every view I guess! I mean Screens, Lists, Navigation bar, etc... basically every view that uses `UIColor.systemBackground` by default.

Comment: @AhmedKamal Light & dark mode color scheme, or custom? For example, you can force a color scheme with `.environment(\.colorScheme, .light)`

Comment: @George no I'm not trying to change the color scheme, I'm trying to override the black background in the dark scheme, for example, using a dark blue background instead of the black background but app-wide, I don't want to set the background for each view separately!

Comment: @George I added a screenshot of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I figure out how to achieve the desired result, here's what I did.

1. Create a color set with the background color you want.
2. Create a color extension for ease of use.

```swift
extension Color {
    static let systemBackground = Color("Background")
}
```

3. In your `ContentView`.

```swift
init() {
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(Color.systemBackground)
    UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(Color.systemBackground)
    UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(Color.systemBackground)
}

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color.systemBackground
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.vertical)

        MyContent()    
    }
}
```

4. And then if `MyContent` is a `List`.

```swift
struct MyContent: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(items) {
                ItemRow($0)
            }
            .listRowBackground(Color.systemBackground)
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that the `.listRowBackground` modified is applied to the `ForEach`, not the `List`.

4. And finally if `MyContent` is a `ScrollView` or any other custom view you can simply use the `background` modified on it.

---

here's the final result.

[image]

---

I was expecting to override the `UIColor.systemBackground` as @swiftpunk mentioned in his answer and all of the views will pick up the new color automatically but it turned out that it just has no effect at all. ‍♂️

Comment: But you did not answered the issue! you just changed the background color of a UI for something else! This is not a valid answer!